# Loading multiple views within a view in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, codeigniter

How do I load multiple views in a view file in Ruby on rails?
I do the following in codeigniter.

```
<?php
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('navbar');
    $this->load->view('masthead');
?>
```

Comment: did not clear multiple view means ?? ..using `layout` or `<%=render :partial => "folder_name/_header"%> <%=render :partial => "folder_name/_navbar"%> <%=render :partial => "folder_name/_masthead"%> `

Comment: Please read about layouts and rendering in Rails. 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look in to the concept of layouts and partials. See the [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) on this.

From the guide, an example of pulling in partials:

```
<%= render "shared/ad_banner" %>
<h1>Products</h1>
<p>Here are a few of our fine products:</p>
...
<%= render "shared/footer" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= render "shared/ad_banner" %>
<h1>Products</h1>
<p>Here are a few of our fine products:</p>
...
<%= render "shared/footer" %>
```

and footer, ad_banner files should be renamedto _footer or _ad_banner in the views folder.